# How can I fix an error in Xcode that shows an unknown class in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode

I try to compile my project and I got the following error:

```
2021-02-05 14:33:32.012929-0300 testeNovaView[3811:50182] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC13testeNovaView9VIewFile2 in Interface Builder file.
```

I try to open the storyboard file as a source code, but I can't find any reference from the class _TtC13testeNovaView9VIewFile2.

Where is that reference?

Comment: Look for `VIewFile2` instead.

Comment: This is the custom class that I use for the view, but what I need to look inside the file?

Comment: Your storyboard found this class but it didn't find the implementation of your class. Make sure the file and the storyboard have the same target, and double check the module of your view in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem.

I deleted the class some time ago, but didn't remove from the ViewController before remove the file.

I created the file again attach to the view Controller.

After that I remove the file from the view Controller, I create another file and put it in the viewController.

The error has gone now.